# Hadoop jar or /bin/hadoop jar

Tags: hadoop

Which is the difference between running 
a map reduce job doing

```
/bin/hadoop -jar /file.jar input output
```

and import jars in eclipse and run the code ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first command runs the job on the Hadoop cluster as configured in `$HADOOP_HOME/conf`. This cluster might be remote, might be a pseudo-distributed cluster or might be local.

Running in Eclipse runs it locally. It runs the mappers and reducers locally in the same JVM.

Comment: i can't configure hadoop using the jar in eclipse?                   Job job = new Job(conf, "word count");   conf is not configurable?

Comment: Yes you can. If you don't configure otherwise, it will try to run locally. I assumed that was the essence of the question.